# Full screen in one tab of UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Currently, five UIViewControllers are switched via a UITabBarController. How can I hide the TabBar and provide a full-screen for one of the UIViewControllers?

For example:

- The middle tab is clicked
- The UITabBarController TabBar is hidden
- The UIViewController takes full screen (hides status bar also)
- When one button in the middle is clicked, switch to the first tab (status bar resumes,  UITabBarController TabBar resumes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put the view controller in a navigation controller and set the view controller's `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property to `YES`. Hiding the status bar can be done using `statusBarHidden` property of the shared application object.

Comment: Thank you - that is exactly the information I'm looking for. I tried a number of other suggestions but this is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

First, right-click the tab bar in Interface Builder and drag "delegate" to "File's Owner".

Then, add the following method to the tab bar controller:

```
– (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void) {
        tabBar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 480);
    }];
}
```

and when a button is clicked, add the tabbar as an outlet to the tab bar controller,
and then do the following when the button is pressed:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void) {
        tabBarController.tabBar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 431);
}];
```

Done!

Answer (score 1):

To hide the tab bar, you can use:

```
    tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```

you can call this from the `viewWillAppear` method of the controller associated to the middle tab bar view, or in your tab bar controller delegate's `–tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:`

You will have to do the opposite in `viewWillAppear` of all other view controllers, or when clicking the "resume" button;

In order to hide the status bar:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

at the same places as above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by doing the following.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

segue.destinationViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES

}
```