# HidesBottomBarWhenPushed leaves indicator

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios6, monotouch.dialog

I have a settings dialog that I want to be full screen and cover the tab bar at the bottom of the screen. I used [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6282104/132599) and added `HidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to my view controller and it does hide the tab bar. Unfortunately it leaves behind the little triangle indicator subview that is displayed by the `UITabBarController` subclass.

[image]

I'm assuming there is some form of notification that I can subscribe to in order to hide the indicator but I don't know what that is. A little help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer this myself because I think it's worth recording for future reference. I have a `SettingsDialogViewController` I wire up in the `ViewDidLoad()` method of my `HomeDialogViewController`:

```
NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem("Settings", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (e, sender) => {
    ActivateController (_settingsDvc());
});
```

The `SettingsDialogViewController` is created with `HidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`. So when the settings dialog is activated, the bottom bar is hidden which causes the `ViewWillLayoutSubviews()` method of the `CustomTabBarController` to be called. By overriding that method I can set the visibility of my indicator based on whether the visible view controller (e.g. `SettingsDialogViewController`) hides the bottom bar when pushed. When that view controller is popped the indicator will automatically reappear.

```
public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews () {
    base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews ();
    var selectedVc = SelectedViewController as UINavigationController;
    indicator.Hidden = selectedVc != null && selectedVc.VisibleViewController.HidesBottomBarWhenPushed;
}
```

A final note, I found that the animation that occurred when activating the new settings view would display a black band across the screen below the status bar. I resolved this by setting the `AutoResizingMask` in the "from" view controller.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad () {
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem("Settings", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (e, sender) => {
        ActivateController (_settingsDvc());
    });
    View.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could post a NSNotification when you set the bar to hidden using the method described here?
[Can't access TabBarController from ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546906/cant-access-tabbarcontroller-from-imageview/13546952#13546952)